How to automatically retrieving full version in CentOS Repo Files
Encountered an error with yum update, so I manually modified the repo file located at /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
File content:
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
#mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/7.9.2009/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

The CentOS repo file path is hardcoded to version 7.9.2009.
How can I automatically fetch the environment parameters?
Previously used $releasever but it only retrieved the integer version (7).

The error with YUM is due to CentOS END OF LIFE. Switch to a supported operating system.

The EOL shouldn't have broken in-place operations. This didn't happen with EL6. It's actually a crappy move.

@ewwhite The change is that there is no supported CentOS releases, so there is no reason to maintain mirrors and upgrade path. For EL6 there was valid reasons to maintain mirrors and upgrade path. For the sake of security it's good that the mirrors are down, so people get error messages.

I support an appliance OS that's based on EL7. There's a massive install base out there. Breaking mirrors and workflows is not the way.

When should they step down the mirrors? And what should they do to make people switch to supported systems? The fact that there's a massive install base is a collective problem for all of the IT ecosystem.

This is implied with EOL. Right now, there are thousands of people scrambling to make excuses for the problems caused by not planning for the end of this product's lifecycle.

@GregAskew I work with cybersecurity in OT settings... "But noone targets Windows NT 4 anymore"...

I ended up changing to a mirror from kernel.org to keep existing EL7 systems intact:
https://archive.kernel.org/centos-vault/7.9.2009
[base]
name=CentOS-7 - Base
baseurl=https://archive.kernel.org/centos-vault/7.9.2009/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

